# Android 12 - Emulator (Xamarin.Android )

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have been trying to find some reliable solution to this but I couldn't. I have added `Android 11 - S` which is an Android 12 Beta image in Android SDKs as shown in the following screenshot

[image]

But when I go and try to create the Emulator device in Device Manager I don't see this API in the list

[image]

What Am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From document [Android 12 Preview](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/overview), we find that :

> The Android 12 Preview program runs from February 2021 until the final
> public release to AOSP and OEMs, planned for later in the year. At key
> development milestones, we'll deliver updates for your development and
> testing environments. Each includes SDK tools, system images,
> emulators, API reference, and API diffs.[image]

Since it's still in beta, there's definitely some instability, so for that reason, it's still not released. We need to wait patiently for the final release.

Comment: Sure, but don't you agree we should be able to test our apps on Beta to ensure a smooth transition when the final release is out instead of wait for a stable release? This time is getting wasted which should be spent on testing apps on android 12. Surely beta is not stable, but we understand that.

Comment: Is it any update about this topic? I can see the Android S available, but not in the emulator.

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 2):

Final release planned for early 2022.
[image]

In Visual Studio you can find Android 12 here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In VS2022 17.0.5, Android 12 is available as a choice in the emulators list. However, be warned. Debugging/deploying android Xamarin in VS 2022 as of this version is sloowwwwww. Anyone with any leads on that, please hit me up!